# UIView animation completion block execute immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

```
-(void)methodXXXX {

       [UIView animateWithDuration:11 animations:^{
               //...some animation changes...
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                  [_fallBtn removeFromSuperview];
                  _fallBtn = nil;
            }
       }];
}
```

I call this method at `-viewDidAppear` , while it directly call **completion block**.

Why? Is there any strange things ive missed?

I found one more wired thing:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES; //If set YES, it will directly call -animationDidStop method; if NO, the animation execute while never call -animationDidStop
    pathAnimation.duration = 10;
    pathAnimation.delegate = self; //here I implement the -animationDidStop method
```

Comment: call the block with delayed one

Comment: Is there any code inside animation block?

Comment: Please check below code that i posted. May be it help you.

Comment: Most likely the "animation changes" do not cause any animatable property of any view in the view controller's view hierarchy to be changed. If no animatable property changed, then the animation will complete instantly.

Comment: Were is the `[TargetView.layer addAnimation:YourAnimation forKey:@"animationID"];` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
         [self performSelector:@selector(methodXXXX) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
    }

-(void)methodXXXX {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:11 animations:^
            //...some animation changes...
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [_fallBtn removeFromSuperview];
            _fallBtn = nil;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:11 delay:"add some delay and try" options:0 animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```